# Is this code correct for printing an array in PHP? Because it isn´t working

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, drupal-7

I want to print the $tabs array in Drupal 7.
So, I´ve tried adding this code inside my node.tpl.php:

```
  <?php
  echo '<div class="btn-group">';
  foreach($tabs as $tab=>$link) {
    echo '<button class="btn"><a href="$link">$tab</a></button>';
  };
  echo '</div>';
  ?>
```

But, it´s not printing anything... so I´m sure this is somewhat wrong.
Maybe because this should be inside the `page.tpl.php`? Is there a syntax problem that I didn´t catch?

Thanks for your help!!

Rosamunda

Comment: What does `var_dump($tabs)` produce?

Comment: The variables are not replaced by their values, because you used single quotes instead of double quotes. However, there should still be some output...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem that I see is that you are attempting to print variables that are contained inside of single quotes.  PHP does not interpolate variables inside of single quotes, but it will inside of double quotes.  Try changing your echo to this:

```
echo '<button class="btn"><a href="' . $link .'">' . 
    $tab . '</a></button>';
```

From the manual:

> Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape 
>   sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in 
>   single quoted strings.

For more information see the manual entry for [Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: +1, but would suggest that for code readability you don't do this.  I use comma-separated lists of things for echo instead.  Also, use `htmlspecialchars()` to ensure valid HTML.

Comment: But even with single quotes, there should still be some output, but she said that it is not printing anything.

Comment: Using single quotes for attributes instead of escaping would be much cleaner.

Comment: All good comments, and I and I'm sure the OP appreciate the feedback.  Concerning the readability, I've updated the answer but used his current style initially for expediency.

Comment: var_dump($tabs) returns NULL. But I don´t understand, because there IS a $tabs array...

Comment: @Rosamunda if var_dump saith, it is so.  Please update your question with where `$tabs` is being initialized in your code, along with any other code that modifies it.  Could be you're setting it via a function call that is returning null.

Answer (score 0):

referring to variables like that works only with double quotes, not single quotes, so it will have to be

```
 echo '<button class="btn"><a href="'.$link.'">'.$tab.'</a></button>';
```

or

```
echo "<button class=\"btn\"><a href=\"$link\">$tab</a></button>";
```

this probably won't fix your code though.

Comment: But the error must be somewhere else because with single quotes there would be at least the variable names printed out, but she said it's printing nothing.